# Uniqueness property for the space of finite measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu(x)=0,~\forall f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$$
Then is it true that $\mu =0$?

We know that the result is true for $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, which is a subspace of the above.

Edit after the comments of Kavi Rama Murthy Sir:

Is the result also true for complex measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we prove this for real measures the result for complex measures follows by just taking real and imaginary parts. Any real measure is the difference of two positive finite measures. So what we have to prove is the following:
if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two finite positive measures such that $\int f d\mu=\int f d\nu$ for all $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ then  $\mu =\nu$.

For this note that given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ such that $\mu ([-N,N])^{c}) <\epsilon$ and $\nu ([-N,N])^{c}) <\epsilon$. There exists $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ and $f(x)=1$ for $|x| \leq N$. If $g$ is any bounded continuous function then $fg \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ so $\int fg d\mu=\int fg d\nu$. I now leave it to you put these together to conclude that $\int g d\mu=\int g d\nu$. The fact that this hods for all bounded continuous$f$ implies that $\mu =\nu$. [This is standard and it is part of Portmanteus's Theorem characterizing weak convergence of probability measures].

Comment: sir i am thinking that, there exists h, a complex borel function such that |h|=1 and $\int fd\mu= \int fhd|\mu|$. If h is real then $hd|\mu|=0$ implies $|\mu|=0$ as |h|=1, implies $\mu=0$. If h is complex then will break h into real and imaginary and apply above separately. Are there any flaw?

Comment: The argument for going from the real to the complex case is simpler. We can write $\mu =\mu_1+i\mu_2$ where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are real measures. For any real valued function $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$  we get $\int f d\mu_1=0$ and $\int f d\mu_2=0$ , so $\mu_1=\mu_2=0$ from the real case.

Comment: sir, I had a tough time to proof the fact that "For any finite signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R} satisfying $\int fd\mu=0,\forall f\in C_b(\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu=0$". Can you please elaborate how it is following from Portmanteus's theorem or cite a book or attach a link where I can find the result. Thank you

Comment: Let $C$ be any closed set and $C_n=\{x:d(x,C) <\frac 1 n\}$. There exists a  continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)=1$ for $x \in C$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in X\setminus C_n$ with $0 \leq f \leq 1$. Hence $\mu(C) = \int_C f d\mu \leq \int f d\mu =\int f d\nu \leq \nu(C_n)$. Let $ n \to \infty$. We get $\mu (C) \leq \nu (C)$. Similarly $\nu (C) \leq \mu (C)$. Hence $\mu (C)=\nu(C)$ for all closed sets $C$. This implies $\mu (C)=\nu(C)$  for all Borel sets $C$.

Answer (score 4):

For all $n=1,2,3,\dots$ there exists a non-negative function $f \in \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{c}}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f=1$ on $[-n,n]$. Therefore, for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$

\begin{equation}
\mu([-n,n]) \leq \int_\mathbb{R} f d \mu = 0.
\end{equation}

By countable subadditivity $\mu(\mathbb{R})=0$, and we are done.

Comment: The question is more interesting for complex measures. For positive measures this answer is fine.

Comment: @Kavu Rama Murthy Sir, can you shed some light for complex measure?

Comment: Then I guess the total variation $|\mu|$ of the complex measure $\mu$ will do the job. @KaviRamaMurthy sir

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji It is more complicated than that. It is not obvious that $\int f d\|\mu|=0$ for $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Oopps, I missed that. So can you please write an answer or give me a hint for the complex measure! Thank you.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir, can you please suggest me some book for further reading for this. Thanking you